# convert std::string to LPCSTR with trailing or leading '\0'

Tags: c++, stdstring, lpcstr

How can I convert std::string to LPCSTR while preserving '\0' characters?

I want to use the result on OPENFILENAME.lpstrFilter which requires the filter to contain '\0' as delimiters.

std::string.c_str() seems to strip and trim '\0'

Thanks in advance!

==========================

(How do I properly add a comment to the responses like a reply post in a forum?)

After reading your comments, I went on to double check this snippet:

```
std::string filter = "Terrain Configuration (*.tcfg)\0*.tcfg\0\0";
const char* f1 = "Terrain Configuration (*.tcfg)\0*.tcfg\0\0";
const char* f2 = filter.c_str();
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
 char c1 = *(f1 + i); // works
 char c2 = *(f2 + i); // doesn't work. beyond the first \0, it's garbage.
}
```

Am I mistaken on how c_str() or LPCSTR works?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839%28VS.85%29.aspx : `lpstrFilter: The last string in the buffer must be terminated by two NULL characters.`.  You need **two** NULL characters at the end for that parameter to work correctly; `c_str()` by design only has one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C_STR doesn't strip the NUL characters. The error is likely in the way you are constructing the STD::string.

Comment: c_str does NOT strip the null, but be cautious, it returns a pointer which is still owned by the string class, so you must make sure to copy the contents

Comment: Please see edited question with the snippet. It's in the same scope, isn't it?

Comment: Regardless, Alexander's point is that in your snippet the filter std::string is not being initialised with your full input because the constructor will stop reading at the first nul. As per Steve's answer below you need to use `std::string filter("Terrain Configuration (*.tcfg)\0*.tcfg\0\0", 40);` I think.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, std::string handles embedded '\0' characters correctly.

However, when interfacing with const char*, extreme care must be taken.

In this case, the problem already occurs during *constructing* the string with:

```
std::string filter = "Terrain Configuration (*.tcfg)\0*.tcfg\0\0"; // wrong
```

Here you construct a std::string from a const char*. As the constructor doesn't know how many characters to use for constructing the std::string, it stops at the first '\0'.

One could copy the characters one by one oneself, but there is a better way: use the contructor that requires two iterators to the char array, one with the begin and one with the end:

```
const char filter_[] = "Terrain Configuration (*.tcfg)\0*.tcfg\0\0"; 
std::string filter(filter_, filter_ + sizeof(filter_));
```

It looks horrible, but hopefully you won't do this that frequently in your code.

Update: Or with appropiate definitions of begin() and end() templates (as per James Kanze's comment):

```
const char filter_[] = "Terrain Configuration (*.tcfg)\0*.tcfg\0\0"; 
std::string filter(begin(filter_), end(filter_));
```

Comment: That's sizeof(filter_) - 1 if the string constant already has the

Comment: Sorry, not used to this interface:

That's sizeof(filter_) - 1 if the string constant already
contains the double \0.  Initializing an array with a string
constant automatically appends a '\0'.

And of course, this use of sizeof will break when the char is
changed to wchar_t.  Better would be to use the usual template
functions begin(filter_), end(filter_), e.g.:
 std::string( begin( filter_ ), end( filter_ ) );

Comment: @James Kanze: Thanks for pointing at the begin() and end() templates, I didn't know them yet.

Comment: @James Kanze: wrt the -1, I considered it harmless to have three '\0' at the end, and didn't want to complicate the answer too much. My choice would have been to omit the second '\0' at the end of the string constant, with a comment that the compiler will add a second one.

Answer (score 2):

The `length()` of your `string` is what you need to use to ensure all characters are included, provided it was properly constructed in the first place to include the embedded `\0` characters.

For an `LPCSTR` valid while `cString` is in scope:

```
#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

string source("mystring");
boost::scoped_array<char> cString(new char[source.length() + 1]);

std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), cString.get());
cString[source.length()] = 0;

LPCSTR rawStr = cString.get();
```

Without scoped_array:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

string source("mystring");
LPSTR rawStr = new char[source.length() + 1];

std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), rawStr);
rawStr[source.length()] = 0;

// do the work here

delete[] rawStr;
```

EDIT:
In your `filter` init, the constructor of `string` only includes data up to the first `\0` char. This makes sense - how else would it not to stop copying data when all it has in hand is `const char *`?  Try this with:

```
const char f3[] = "Terrain Configuration (*.tcfg)\0*.tcfg\0\0";
std::string filter(f3, sizeof(f3));
```

Comment: hmm... I could copy one char at a time but just hoping there's a faster way.

Comment: @Jake - `std::copy` removes the need for a bye-by-byte copy loop.  If you remove the `scoped_array` above it might be clearer, just new directly into `rawStr`.  See edit.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on further life-cycle of std::string.

For example you can append terminal zero manually:

```
std::string test("init");
test += '\0';
```

This causes length to be increased by one. Or just create another instance of std::string with zero appended